# Не получается закрыть окно Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Помогите закрыть окно при нажатии на крестик через Jquery, не меняя структуру HTML и CSS

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  $(".choose-button").click(function() {
    $(".share-image-shadow").toggle();
  });

  $(".share-block").click(function() {
    $('.share-background-mask').show();

    $(this).find('.share-buttons').show();
    $('#close-btn').show();
    console.log("test");

  });

  $('#close-btn').click(function() {
    $(".share-background-mask").hide();
    $('.share-buttons').hide();
    $('#close-btn').hide();
  });



});
```

```css
.share-image-shadow {
  display: none;
}

.share-background-mask {
  position: absolute;
  display: none;
}

.share-background-mask-two {
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 19;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  background-color: #00000061;
}

.share-block {
  cursor: pointer;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: #eee;
}

.share-buttons {
  position: fixed;
  width: 200px;
  z-index: 20;
  background-color: #FFFFFF;
  display: none;
  height: 200px;
  text-align: center;
}

#close-btn {
  width: 25px;
  height: 20px;
  color: #FFFFFF;
  background-color: #D20A11;
  font-weight: 100;
  cursor: pointer;
  text-align: center;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 999;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<div class="choose-button">Button</div>

<div class="share-image-shadow">

  <div class="share-image-block">
    <div class="share-block">

      <div class="share-buttons">
        <div class="share-buttons-block">
          <div class="share-block-left">
            <h4>Block!</h4>
          </div>
          <div class="share-block-right">
            <h4>test!</h4>

            <p>test test</p>
            <div id="close-btn">x</div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="share-background-mask">
  <div class="share-background-mask-two"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Вопрос поставлен не совсем корректно. Используя js, невозможно изменять поведение элементов на странице, не затрагивая либо html, либо css. Собственно, элемент на странице - это набор свойств - цвет, размер, позиция, контент и т.п. js предоставляет методы для работы с этими свойствами. Любое изменение поведения элемента на странице = изменение свойства элемента.

Answer (score 0):

Нужно добавить `event.stopPropagation()` в обработчик. Подробнее о том как события всплывают можете почитать [здесь](https://learn.javascript.ru/event-bubbling)

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  $(".choose-button").click(function() {
    $(".share-image-shadow").toggle();
  });

  $(".share-block").click(function() {
    $('.share-background-mask').show();

    $(this).find('.share-buttons').show();
    $('#close-btn').show();
    console.log("test");

  });

  $('#close-btn').click(function(e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
    $(".share-background-mask").hide();
    $('.share-buttons').hide();
    $('#close-btn').hide();
  });



});
```

```css
.share-image-shadow {
  display: none;
}

.share-background-mask {
  position: absolute;
  display: none;
}

.share-background-mask-two {
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 19;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  background-color: #00000061;
}

.share-block {
  cursor: pointer;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: #eee;
}

.share-buttons {
  position: fixed;
  width: 200px;
  z-index: 20;
  background-color: #FFFFFF;
  display: none;
  height: 200px;
  text-align: center;
}

#close-btn {
  width: 25px;
  height: 20px;
  color: #FFFFFF;
  background-color: #D20A11;
  font-weight: 100;
  cursor: pointer;
  text-align: center;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 999;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<div class="choose-button">Button</div>

<div class="share-image-shadow">

  <div class="share-image-block">
    <div class="share-block">

      <div class="share-buttons">
        <div class="share-buttons-block">
          <div class="share-block-left">
            <h4>Block!</h4>
          </div>
          <div class="share-block-right">
            <h4>test!</h4>

            <p>test test</p>
            <div id="close-btn">x</div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="share-background-mask">
  <div class="share-background-mask-two"></div>
</div>
```